# how do I use the key or keyCode functions in p5?

Tags: string, variables, p5.js

I am trying to take the output from the `keyPressed` element to read what I presume is the ASCII value of whatever key is pressed into a string type variable. I've looked through the online Processing site and they suggest using either the `key` or `keyCode` function but I am confused as to how this might work.

Comment: Consider also the [`keyIsDown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76137465/6243352) function, useful for situations when you need to detect multiple keys at once.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple. For example:

```
let printedValue = "";
function draw() {

}

function keyPressed() {
  printedValue = keyCode
  print(printedValue)
}
```

Essentially what you are doing is getting the JavaScript Event KeyCode for the key that is being pressed. For example, for `'a'` the output will be 65, for `'ArrowUp'` - 38, etc (check [this link](https://keycode.info/) for all the JavaScript Event KeyCodes).

You can also use just the key function, so change your line to this:

```
  printedValue = key
```

This will return actual name of the key, e.g. simply `'a', 'b', 'ArrowUp'`, etc.

Comment: ok thanks...ill try this out later today and let you know...i persume that key and KeyCode are mutully exsclusive so to cover all the possible types of keyPressed events I should write: printedValue = key or keyCode; ???