# Up and down Movement in p5.js (and using WASD)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

How can I use the keyboard to make a character move in p5? I mean, more then left and right... I would also like to use the WASD keys. I've used this (shape as a placeholder):

https://editor.p5js.org/TheDiamondfinderYT/present/8ZqV2LsVB

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW||keyCode === 65) {
    left()
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW||keyCode === 68) {
    right();
    
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    up()
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    down()
  }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not make your question "more silly". Post your question in a neutral tone, trying to keep it factual and short. That way other people can understand your question easier :)

Comment: Okay then, I changed it!

Comment: Ok great. If you put a `console.log(keyCode)` in your function, does it log and what do you get?

Comment: I just get 37 and 39, the other keys don't read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made a few mistakes. For example, in this code:

```
else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW||keyCode === 68) {
    right();
    
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    up()
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    down()
  }
}
```

the `if` statements for `UP_ARROW` and `DOWN_ARROW` are *inside* the `if` statements for `RIGHT_ARROW`, when they shouldn't be. [Here](https://editor.p5js.org/KamakuraYaru/sketches/7zoq72QjZ) is a version I cleaned up for you, you can just copy the code and moving should work fine.

Comment: Haha, fun fact: If you press left and then A, you go left twice as fast

Comment: i... I  can't believe I did that... Well, thanks! I'm going to try to fix the speed glitch though

Comment: Mistakes happen all the time, and are perfectly normal. Good luck fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

Offering a variant on what you're working on here: for games and many applications, you need to be able to handle multiple key presses at once in the `draw` loop. You can use `keyIsDown(keyCode)` to achieve this, as shown in the example below, which also handles WASD.

```js
const player = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  speed: 5,
  up() {
    this.y -= this.speed;
  },
  down() {
    this.y += this.speed;
  },
  left() {
    this.x -= this.speed;
  },
  right() {
    this.x += this.speed;
  },
};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) || keyIsDown(87)) {
    player.up();
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) || keyIsDown(65)) {
    player.left();
  }  
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) || keyIsDown(68)) {
    player.right();
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) || keyIsDown(83)) {
    player.down();
  }
  
  rect(player.x, player.y, 20, 20);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```